# Linking id codes in one struct with string values from another - SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have two simple structs populated from two separate JSON files.  One is essentially a fixture list with with a list of "fixtures" described by a series of 'id's' (dateid, competitionid, team1id, team2id) and a second struct which describes the team itself (teamid,teamName, teamDefAbility, teamMidAbility, teamAttAbility)

I can scroll over each struct using simple code and all looks correct.  For example the code below shows all of the entries in the fixture list and displays the `fixturesid` and the two teams id's `team1id` and `team2id` that compete in that match.

```
ScrollView {
  VStack {
    ForEach(self.fixtures, id \.id) { fixtures in
      HStack {
        Text(fixtures.dateid)
        Text(fixtures.team1id)
        Text(fixtures.team2id)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is instead be able to show the proper team name and/or attribute details about that team rather than the id code.  So I need something that links the `fixtures.team1id` with the `teams.teamid` and uses this link to display `teams.name`

For reference there are similar tables that link `dateid` to proper dates and `competitioni`d to more information about the tournament so any code ideally should be generic or easily modifiable to be used in multiple other instances.

I should also note that despite all of the data in the id fields in the JSONs being numeric, swift won't let me decode these as `Int` and I can only read them in as `String`.  As such, if I have to use `Int` in the solution then I will also need to work out how to recast the variables in the structs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some comments, I assume you have many fixtures per team so one option is to create a cache (dictionary) for your teams with the id as key and then do a look-up to get the full team info and another option is to create a third type that contains the values from both of the json files merged together and then use that type in your view. Another comment is that whatever solution you choose do all the hard work in a separate struct or class so the view is simple and only about showing the data and finally, I don't understand your concern about id being a string since they are as easy to compare.

Answer (score 0):

I've thought a bit more about this and I thought I would pose one possible answer to my own question and would like peoples feedback on it.

As stated I wanted to try and link the `teamid` in the fixture table, to the teamid's `hometeam` and `awayTeam` in the team table and get it to show the team name.  My two structs were set out as follows:

```
struct Teams: Codable, {
  let teamID: Int
  let teamName: String
}

struct Fixtures: Codable, {
  let id: Int
  let homeTeam: Int
  let awayTeam: Int
}
```

and they were populated from JSON data using an extension as follows:

```
let teams: [Teams] = bundle.main.decode(file: "teamTable.json")
let fixtures: [Fixtures] = bundle.main.decode(file: "fixtureTable.json")
```

In order to show the team name instead of the teamID when displaying the fixture information I have used a `firstIndex(where)` func with a predicate of the teamID from the fixture list.  The code to do this is as follows (all wrapped in a `ForEach` for the complete fixture list)

```
Text("\(teams[teams.firstIndex(where: { $0.teamID == fixtures.homeTeam})!].teamName)")
```

This works for me so it achieves what I wanted but I was wondering if this is acceptable or if Ive done something sinister I shouldn't have.  Also, I force unwrap the Index as xcode reports the array is optional.  Im not sure why this is or whether forcing the unwrap is bad when I know this should never error based in the input jsons?